# Facebook Messenger GIF share from our app to Android doesn't animate but does for ios

Tags: android, facebook, gif, messenger, facebook-messenger

We have created a mobile app to share our own animated GIF's to Messenger. Iphone to Iphone the gif animates in messenger, Iphone to Android AND Android to android the GIF does not animate in Android Messenger. But it animates for the sender in Android Messenger. The strange thing is Giphy GIF animates in android for recipient. And the GIF's used to animate in Android Messenger from our app last week! Any help at all you could give us would be amazing! We have worked so hard creating awesome animated gif's but can't launch.

Comment: I would use the latest SDK and try again, if still having issues I would report a [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/)

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Same issue here (on Android 4.4.4, 5.0.1, 5.1.1, 6.0 - with latest Messenger SDK, even beta one), I've contacted the Messenger support but finally the bug seems related to the Messenger app so it is not possible to fill a bug, I have to report the problem inside the Messenger app. For now no answer... I planned to add gif support to one of my app, so frustrating...